# Delphi Connect To Azure Cache for Redis

Tags: azure, delphi, redis, pascal, azure-redis-cache

I successfully setup the Azure Redis Server (following this steps [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache][1] ). My problem is how can I connect my Delphi App to Azure Cache for Redis? Im using Delphi XE to build VCL Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the redis **AUTH** command (see https://redis.io/commands/auth) having the value from Access Keys on Azure.

```
 IdTCPClient1.Host := 'project.redis.cache.windows.net';
 IdTCPClient1.Port := 6379;
 IdTCPClient1.Connect;
 IdTCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn('auth authentication=youraccesskey');
```